# Loops and functions

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have created a loop that iterates through consecutive dates in an SQL query. The aim is to create a table in R from the SQL output (bigquery). This works by storing the query as a string in R and passing it to Google Cloud. I want to pass a series of small queries this way, iterating on the dates so that I can analyse them in R.

The issue is that it is returning the same values where each query should return a different value. I am sure the issue is not in the SQL but in the way I have set up the loop, function or `lappyl()`

Any clues would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
# Load the package

library(bigrquery)

# create a value for the project ID
projectid = "xyz123"

# create date ranges
start   <- as.Date("2019-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")
end <- as.Date("2019-01-30", format="%Y-%m-%d")

theDate <- start

# create a blank output placeholder
output <- character()

# while loop. Creates series of SQL queries with BETWEEN filters iteratively increasing on consecutive days
while (theDate <= end)
{
  print(paste0('
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT(some_data))
FROM `some_table`
WHERE JoinDate BETWEEN "', format(theDate, "%Y-%m-%d"), '" AND "', format(theDate + 1, "%Y-%m-%d")))
  theDate <- theDate + 1
  
  output <- c(output, sql)
}

# the function

function_out <- function(output) {
  # create a bq_table object
  tb <- bq_project_query(projectid, sql)
  # Store the rows of the data in a tibble
  value <- bq_table_download(tb)
  
  return(value)
}

# apply function and SQL iterations
df <- sapply(output, FUN = function_out, USE.NAMES = FALSE) %>%
  unlist()
df # inspect output
```

Comment: `sql` is not defined within `function_out`. Guess it should be `tb <- bq_project_query(projectid, output)`.

Comment: Yes, good spot. I needed to define output, not sql.

The issue is I get exactly the same result, still.

Comment: In your loop, you need to change the line `print(paste0('` to `sql <- paste0(` and remove the `)` that closed `print()`

Comment: Be sure to always run `theDate <- start` prior to running your `while()` loop as well. As it stands, "theDate" becomes "2019-01-31" at the end of the loop. Looping again without resetting "theDate" means theDate > end.

Comment: Both of these worked! You both correctly identified both mistakes. Thanks.